# Как удалить переменную в C++?

Tags: c++, переменные

Мне хотелось бы чтобы я мог удалить переменную `Y` и объявить ее заново.

У меня есть код:

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int Y = 1;
    // Здесь переменной Y уже не должно существовать.
    int Y = 12;
    // Здесь переменной Y уже не должно существовать.
    string Y = "hello!";

    cout << Y;

    return 0;
 }
```

Я пробовал помещать переменную в `{}`, но тогда она не доступна за ее пределами. Есть ли способы реализовать такое с доступом во всей функции?

Comment: Так а в чем проблема с областью видимости `{ }` ? Если переменная `уже не должна существовать` то о каком доступе во всей функции может идти речь? А вообще зачем это? Чтобы запутать и себя и других?

Comment: Вы ведь уже об этом спрашивали, но не объяснили, для чего это вам нужно.

Comment: Если честно я сам не знаю зачем, мне просто очень очень очень интересно.

Comment: Может быть, вам нужен язык с динамической типизацией. Однако переиспользование переменных ни к чему хорошему не приведёт

Comment: Зачем же так жестоко? - я про "уничтожить, раздавить, удалить" в заголовке...

Comment: Понял, спасибо. А про жестоко - это кликбейт :) Лад, все, расходимся.

Comment: Во время написания этого вопроса ни одна переменная не пострадала :)

Answer (score 3):

Так а в чем проблема с областью видимости { } ? Если переменная уже не должна существовать то о каком доступе во всей функции может идти речь? А вообще зачем это? Чтобы запутать и себя и других?

```
int main()
{
    {
    int Y = 1;
    }
    // Здесь переменной Y уже не должно существовать - выполнено!
    {
    int Y = 12;
    }
    // Здесь переменной Y уже не должно существовать  - выполнено!

    string Y = "hello!"; // здесь у Y видимость до конца функции.
    cout << Y;

    return 0;
 }
```

В С/С++ статическая типизация - однажды объявленная переменная не меняет свой тип. Это помогает не допускать ошибок.